# ionic load a remote json with httpClient

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm new to angular and I would like to fetch data from an API : https://randomuser.me/

I tried lot of tutorials and methods but I am in trouble to load the data into an other json.

```
export class TreeComponent {

   text: string;
   public items;
   test:string;

   data;

   constructor(public http: HttpClient) {

   this.text = 'Hello World work in progress !';

   this.items = [{
       gender: '',
       name: {
         title:'',
         first:'',
         last:''
       },
       picture: {
          large: ''
       }
      }]

   this.loadData();

   loadData(){
      this.http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/')
        .subscribe((data: Config) =>  {

        this.items = data["results"];

        console.log(this.items.gender)
      });
  }
}
```

I'm trying to fill my items variable and it works for the html file :

```
<div>

<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
      {{item.gender}} <br>
    {{item.name.title}} <br>
    {{item.name.first}} <br>
    {{item.name.last}} <br>
    <img src="{{item.picture.large}}" alt="portrait ">

  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

I've the name, gender and title on my page, but when I try to use my variable items in my code like this for example :

```
this.data = {
  name: items.name.first,
  designation: "bar",
  subordinates: []
}
```

I've an error saying items.name.first is undefined. I don't know what's I am doing wrong. I already tried lot of way (using promises, observers...) and I didn't found how to fix it.

the console.log(data["results"]) :

```
Array(1)
0:
cell: "(141)-248-3533"
dob: {date: "1977-06-02T18:28:35Z", age: 41}
email: "emily.lewis@example.com"
gender: "female"
id: {name: "", value: null}
location: {street: "6842 saint aubyn street", city: "blenheim", state:"taranaki", postcode: 36604, coordinates: {…}, …}
login: {uuid: "471aac1b-413c-4e60-9ac8-4192837ac253", username:"orangefish205", password: "samuel", salt: "foX3yaYP", md5:"30b244b9b722d02557c6243e9bdb48fc", …}
name: {title: "miss", first: "emily", last: "lewis"}
nat: "NZ"
phone: "(146)-713-2070"
picture: {large: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/52.jpg", 
          medium: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/women/52.jpg", 
          thumbnail: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/52.jpg"}
registered: {date: "2004-04-20T09:57:48Z", age: 14}
```

**proto**: Object
length: 1
**proto**: Array(0)

in my constructor I would like to affect the name from the API to my variable data :

```
 constructor(public http: HttpClient) {

    this.text = 'Hello World work in progress !';

    this.items = [
         {gender: '',
         name: {
           title:'',
           first:'',
           last:''
          },
         picture: {
          large: ''
        }
     }]

this.loadData();

  console.log(this.items[0].name.first)
  this.data = {
     name: this.items[0].name.first,
     designation: "bar",
     subordinates: []
    }
 }
```

Comment: please add to your question what the console log shows

Comment: my console just say that : 'undefined at tree.ts:65'

Comment: and what line is 65 in your tree.ts file?

Comment: this is the console.log(this.items.gender) instruction in my loadData method at the end of the file.

Comment: what does console.log(data["results"]) inside the callback give you?

Comment: it gives me an array of size 1 I'm going to edit my post otherwise it's too long

Comment: try the answer i posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an array back, do this instead:

```
console.log(this.items[0].gender);
```

and to populate your "data" attribute you do:

```
this.data = {
     name: this.items[0].name.first,
     gender: this.items[0].gender,
     picture: this.items[0].picture.medium
}
```

where picture depending on what size of image you see in the response

Comment: ok it's seems to work for the console, I'm getting the male or female, it's seems obvious now you're saying that thanks.
It's working inside my loadData method but now when I'm trying to do a :
    console.log(this.items[0].gender)
 in my constructor i've an empty field (not even an undefined just a blank)

Comment: the scope is in the callback so you cant print outside of it if im understanding you correctly

Comment: ok, I think you understood me sorry if I've an horrible english. In this case Is there a way to affect my json values to my variable items in all my class ?

Comment: not sure what you are trying now, update your question with code on what you are trying

Comment: ok I did it, I would like to put the right name, gender and later picture in my variable data

Comment: It works, thank to you for paying attention and your help.